# Search for substring in string with "DO NOT CARE FLAG"

Tags: java, string

I need to search for substring on a string. The trick is:
-  the is is one letter that I dont care about.
- the letter need to have one letter there, but it doresn't matter which letter.
- the letters is "I", so

Hence, for example the subsrting **"MQINEEIR"** when compared to string:

```
- "MQINEEIR"  - match, same
- "MQINEELR"  - match, one I is L the othe is L
- "MQLNEELR"  - match, both I are L 
- MQXNEEIR   - match becouse X stand for I, but ideally I would like to allow only L. But for simplicity, I will allow it.
```

But

- "MQINEER" is not match becouse I is missing and not letter that stand for it.

  - MQINEEIX  is not match becouse there is X insteadof R, and I only allow for variation of I

I think this could be solved using **pattern matching**, I but not sure how?

Comment: You need to explain better the conditions for a match.  There are too many unspecified possibilities.  For example, what if the target is `MQINEEIX`? or `MQXNEEIR`? How about `MQINEEIRX`?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, are you trying to match on the string `MQINEEIR` where `I` and `L` can be substituted for one another? I would recommend familiarizing yourself with regex

Comment: No, regex won't solve this.

Comment: Tell me if I'm right: MQLNEEIR is a match, MQLNEELR is a match, MQLNEEXR is not a match.

Comment: @T. Claverie Yes ... but it doesn't matter, because for my application if I is not there then, it will be an "L" or "I".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `String.matches(String)` method:

```
String s = "MQLNEELR";
System.out.println(s.matches("MQ.NEE.R"));
```

It could be worthwhile to familiarize yourself with regex.

Comment: Sorry ... "MQLNEELR" was an example, it could be any string so "MQLNEELR"; would be a variable. Unless I could insert "." whenever I see "I" on the string.

Comment: Or, if you need to match substrings, create a matcher like this `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("MQ.NEE.R").matcher(s)` and than scan with `m.find()`.

Comment: @user836026 So, make it a variable. Also, if you're only interested in matching a lower case L or an upper case I instead of any character, you could replace the dot with `[lI]`. Regex is really cool, you may like it.